# Scala: "explicit return" required?

Tags: java, scala, boolean, return

I thought in Scala I don't need to explicit put "return" in the return statement. So I have the following code:

```
  def checkSimple(str1: String, str2: String): Boolean = {

    if (str1 > str2) {
      println("str1 > str2")
      true
    }

    println("str1 <= str2")
    false
  }
```

if I ran my above code with checkSimple("200", "150"), I got wrong result below:

```
str1 > str2
str1 <= str2
```

---

But if I add "return" in front of "true" like below, everything works correctly:

```
  def checkSimple(str1: String, str2: String): Boolean = {

    if (str1 > str2) {
      println("str1 > str2")
      return true
    }

    println("str1 <= str2")
    false
  }
```

---

So is "return" actually required in the return statement line?

Thanks!

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know your intent was to return `true` in the if statement?

Comment: Sometimes `-Xlint` will warn about such mistakes. But FSR it doesn't even warn about `def g(i: Int, j: Int) = { if (i < j) true ; false }`. It warns on `def f = { true ; false }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last expression's value is used as the return so:

```
  def checkSimple(str1: String, str2: String): Boolean = {
    if (str1 > str2) {
      println("str1 > str2")
      true
    } else {
      println("str1 <= str2")
      false
    }
  }
```

will behave the way you expect